# why am i getting list is not defined error in python IDLE?

Tags: python, list, nameerror

[image]

> I created an object of tictactoe class and then called display method on it :I'm getting error message saying List_1 is not defined
>   Blockquote

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    a.display()
  File "C:/Users/Kunall/Documents/#1 Code/#Projects/tic_tac_toe_0.2.py", line 6, in display
for l in list_1:
NameError: name 'list_1' is not defined
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Don't post images of code. You've been here for over 3 years, it's time to figure out how to paste and format code in a question.

Comment: If you want to reference the classs variable `list_1` you need to do `self.list_1` - it will check the instance namespace and fallback to the class namespace. `list_1` by itself would just be a variable local to that method. Design wise, I think `list_1` is better as an instance variable initialized in `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `list_1` you should use `self.list_1` and similarly `self.uc_list`